# Физическое нажатие кнопок

Tags: c++, ассемблер

Как определить именно физическое нажатие кнопки а не эмулированное (например, с помощью программы или макроса на мыши)? Желательно на с++, но если не как, то может быть на ассемблере что-то есть.

Comment: Если и возможно, то очень сильно зависит от операционной системы, а ее вы не указали

Comment: @Maks Fall попытка победить читтеров?

Comment: ос windows. да, что то вроде попытки запретить использовать хотя бы макросы на мыше

Comment: Вы понимаете, что компании тратят миллионы, что бы найти решения такого читерства, а Вы хотите просто так на форуме получить?

Comment: @KoVadim понимаю. в игре RUST например с помощью античита EAC уже уже не пускает в игру если у тебя мышь с возможностью записи макроса. так что я думаю это вполне возможно. другое дело что это отпугнёт многих геймеров

Comment: ну отпугнет пару школьников. делов то. Но по факту макросы можно найти просто тем, что пользователь слишком быстро все вводит.

Comment: @KoVadim если не смогу не чего найти так и придется делать. но вообще там же можно правильные тайминги выставить и тогда просто не будет смысла в этих проверках

Comment: почти все известные мне "чудо системы защиты от читеров" просто проверяют наличие определенных процессов в памяти.

Comment: @KoVadim уже нашёл что то похожее. изучаю